# printing elements with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript at the moment and the code below isn't producing the results I thought it would:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    document.write(links[i]);
}
```

When I run this code, it writes 1 element from the array. I want it to return everything (there are over 1,000 in `links`)

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Check out my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628310/is-there-an-error-in-my-code-or-does-it-have-to-do-with-my-firefox-12-browser/10631004#10631004 the issue is same with the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

links is a live NodeList (see [.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName)). Any change to the links on the page will be reflected immediatly in the list.

With the first `document.write` you're overwriting the current document (if used after the document has loaded) so the `links` list will be empty.

Use `console.log()` instead of `document.write` and have a look at the Javascript console of you're browser.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    console.log(links[i]);
}
```